# Include all of these commands in one big MySQL statement?

Tags: mysql, sql

For an assignment, I have to include all of these keywords in one big MySQL statement: select, from, where, group by, order by, inner join, insert, update, delete.

Obviously all but the last 3 are easy to include in 1 statement.

However, I'm having a problem with using union on 2 SQL statements (one with select, etc. and the other with insert).

For example, I have:

```
SELECT * FROM Database 
INNER JOIN (O_Database INNER JOIN ...) 
ON ...
GROUP BY ...
ORDER BY ...
UNION 
INSERT INTO Database (...) VALUES (...)
```

But I run into errors with using UNION this way. Is there a simple statement that includes all of these keywords?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see no solution to put DELETE in there. You can build a select statement with all the stuff required and use this in an INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Statement. But DELETE? No. In Oracle this would be possible by using the MERGE statement, but this is not available in MySQL. So I guess, there is no solution to the task given.

```
INSERT INTO ...
SELECT ... -- using from, where, group by, order by, and inner join here
ON DUPLICATE KEY 
UPDATE ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can do something like

```
INSERT INTO A
SELECT whatever FROM B;
```

or

```
UPDATE A
INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM B ) C ON A.id = C.id
SET A.whatever = C.whatever;
```

or

```
DELETE 
FROM A WHERE A.whatever IN (SELECT whatever FROM B);
```

But you can not combine  `DELETE` and `UPDATE` or `UPDATE` and `INSERT`. Just one of the operations with a `SELECT`.